# Is it possible to watch fields inside a json with dynamic keys?

Tags: angularjs

I have a json object like this:

```
{"threshold":{"FY16":{"min":50,"max":100},"FY15":{"min":25,"max":75}}}
```

Here `FY16` and `FY15` are dynamic based on user input. Now I want to watch the changes in `min` and `max` attributes.

What I can do is watch for changes in `threshold` array and iterate to find the changes manually. Is it possible to do avoid this manual iteration?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can bind it to the html {{your-json-object | json}}

Comment: This json is not displayed in template. This is used only in controller and i am only trying to watch the changes happening in the json. Do you mind providing a fiddle or code for this? Thanks in advance.